# How to extract data from N2Y0.com

Tags: python

I tried to extract values with BeautifilSoup from this website
http://www.n2yo.com/?s=25164 because is a work to my final degree project to finish university.
the problem is that i cant have the correct values , can someone help me to get a number values?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import re

request = requests.get('http://www.n2yo.com/?s=25164')

content = request.content
soup = bs(content, 'html.parser')
table = soup.table
table = soup.find(id='trackinginfo')

table_rows = table.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)


   and my output is this

  [u'NORAD ID:', '']
  [u'LOCAL TIME:', '']
  [u'UTC:', '']
  [u'LATITUDE:', '']
  [u'LONGITUDE:', '']
  [u'ALTITUDE [km]:', '']
  [u'ALTITUDE [mi]:', '']
  [u'SPEED [km/s]:', '']
  [u'SPEED [mi/s]:', '']
  [u'AZIMUTH:', u' ']
  [u'ELEVATION:', '']
  [u'RIGHT ASCENSION:', '']
  [u'DECLINATION:', '']
  [u'Local Sidereal Time:', '']
  ['']
  [u'SATELLITE PERIOD:', '']
  ['']
  [u'\n\n\n\n\n <div class="fb-like-box" data-
```

Comment: It's not that simple in the case of this website as it loads the vales using JS. if you print the returned HTML in `request.text`, you won't find the values.. meaning, they haven't been loaded (as Requests doesn't run the pages's JS code).

Comment: I'd suggest using Selenium instead of Requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use this link - `http://www.n2yo.com/sat/instant-tracking.php?s=25544&hlat=51.54619&hlng=-0.47961&d=300&r=1293160274796.1914&tz=GMT+00:00&O=n2yocom&rnd_str=54ea6fad63f992c1bb8c6b19c430e6b6`  I think it would be easier to get the data you need.

http://bheliom.github.io/Satellite-tracking/

Comment: No Problem, One more thing change the ID to -  25164 the link has this one -  s=25544